# The jsonb file is not imported into mongo

Tags: mongodb

[image: 1]

When importing a file, it gives such an error, how to fix it, fix it? Maybe a hint in which direction to dig. The names and paths (as seen in the screenshot, I indicate relative) are correct.

Comment: Please don't use images for code, errors, stack traces/back-traces, text, etc.  Just include the text in a code block.  Was `payments` created by `mongodump`?  Was it from a sharded cluster?

Comment: yes, files created from mongodbdump

Comment: Are you trying to run `mongorestore` from within Compass's `mongosh`?  I don't know for sure, but I don't think that works.  All the mongo-tools are supposed to be run from an OS's commandline.

Comment: ... reference https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/import-export/#import-and-export-data-from-the-command-line

Comment: Tell me please. If you follow the manual (import the file with the button). Then you get an error when importing .bson. I have already tried to do this, I was told to do it through the command line. And through cmd, I don't have half an hour, writes that "mongo" is not an internal or external
command, an executable program or a batch file. Although the global variable is correct. Is there another way?

Comment: From your commandline, is `mongorestore` recognized as a command?

Comment: no, even just "mongo" is not recognized as a command

Comment: `mongorestore` is a standalone program.  You either need to find it, or [install](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-windows/) it. ... or go through a process to extract the collection from the `mongodump` file and then _import_ the JSON.